# How use preference for core widget block class?

Tags: magento2, blocks, widget, class, core

How override core block class for core **Catalog Category Link widget**?
I try:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link"
            type="Vendor\ModuleName\Rewrites\Block\Widget\Catalog\Category\Widget"/>
```

But this is not working.

Although, this is the correct block and I use deBag, I go into it, and it is also described in the widget itself.

Part from **core widget.xml**

```
<widget id="catalog_category_link"
            class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link"
            is_email_compatible="true"
            placeholder_image="Magento_Catalog::images/category_widget_link.png">
        <label translate="true">Catalog Category Link</label>
        <description translate="true">Link to a Specified Category</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="id_path" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10">
                <label translate="true">Category</label>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Widget\Chooser">
                    <data>
                        <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="open" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Category...</item>
                        </item>
                    </data>
                </block>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="anchor_text" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Anchor Custom Text 1234</label>
                <description translate="true">If empty, we'll use the category name here.</description>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Anchor Custom Title</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Template</label>
                <options>
                    <option name="default"
                            value="category/widget/link/link_block.phtml"
                            selected="true">
                        <label translate="true">Category Link Block Template</label>
                    </option>
                    <option name="link_inline" value="category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml">
                        <label translate="true">Category Link Inline Template</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
```

Comment: May this help out? --> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326744/how-to-override-module-catalog-block-widget-link-php-in-magento-2/333629#333629

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this file :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml
```

arround line no.477

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="entityResource" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category</argument>
        </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Actually, the class which you are trying to override is virtual type,
the original class is this one : `Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link`